# How to understand this kind of syntax in Javascript Redux Middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am reading the article to understand the redux middleware from this link: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html

Below code is an example of a logging middleware.

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.log('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  return result
}
```

What I don't understand it below part:

```
const logger = store => next => action =>
```

What does kind of this syntax mean? Are store, next, action parameters for the logger function? What is the different when comparing below code:

```
const logger = (store, next, action) => {}
```

Comment: that link you gave explains the evolution of the function perfectly. it even tells you that the curried function can be expressed nicely using multiple arrow functions. sorry, but this is a case of rtfm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a form of currying.  A very concise form of currying.  If we changed the syntax from arrow functions to classic functions, it would go from this (admittedly confusing) syntax:

```
const logger = store => next => action => { ... }
```

... to this hopefully less confusing syntax:

```
const logger = function (store) {
    return function (next) {
        return function (action) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Does this help clarify it a bit?

Comment: It makes sense. But how to call the function logger?

Comment: I see I can call this function such as:   logger(xxx)(xxx)(xxx). Is this correct?

Comment: @Zhao Yi You don't call it.  You define it and give it to the middleware to call.  Currying lets you write a function that would normally take multiple  arguments in a way where only one argument needs to be given.  The other arguments are defined by the function.  (But yes, if you really wanted to you could call it like that)